# Algorithm - How to build a polygon around a polyline

Tags: google-maps, buffer, gis, polygon, polyline

I am building a web site using googles Map API.
However, as I am on a shared server, I do not have access to a database with spatial extensions.

Given an itinerary, which is nothing more than a series of line segments, I need to build a polygon at a given distance.  For example 10km either side of the itinerary.

This is the classic buffering request, which I have seen as being referenced as the **" Minkowski sum "** algorithm.  After having searched, I have not found a working example of an implementation.

Can anyone help me implement this ... please ?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/). This library contains (among a lot of other things) an Open Source Minkowski sum implementation, which you could analyse. See [here](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Minkowski_sum_2/Chapter_main.html)

Comment: Merci, j'y vais jeter un coup d'oeil.